# Incomplete beta function in MATLAB

Tags: integration, special-functions, matlab

Mathematica is capable of evaluating the [incomplete beta function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Beta.html)

$$ \mathrm{Beta}[z,a,b] = \int_0^z u^{a-1}\left(1-u\right)^{b-1}\,du $$

even when the argument $z$ is negative.  MATLAB's function `betainc(z,a,b)`, however, only allows $z\in[0,1]$.  Do there exist any work-arounds for this (analytical tricks, or better MATLAB functions)?

Comment: Did you look what Mathematica's incomplete beta function's codes are? or Mathematica does not allow people to get a sneakpeak of the codes for built-in functions.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I do not know if Mathematica discloses its algorithms for built-in functions.

Comment: Note that Matlab's [`betainc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/betainc.html) is actually the regularized incomplete beta function. The Mathematica equivalent is actually [`BetaRegularized `](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BetaRegularized.html). Also, `betainc` is a purely numeric function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility is to evaluate the integral that defines the incomplete beta function using quadrature. In Matlab you can use the [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function (use `quadgk` if you have an older version of Matlab)

```
y = integral(@(t)t.^(a-1).*(1-t).^(b-1),0,z)./beta(a,b)
```

where the output is divided by `beta(a,b)` to obtain the [regularized incomplete beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) matching `betainc`. This can be vectorized across `z` with

```
f = @(t)t.^(a-1).*(1-t).^(b-1);
for i = numel(z):-1:1
    y(i) = integral(f,0,z(i));
end
y = y./beta(a,b);
```

The result is about the same speed as using `hypergeom` on my computer.

Also, note the complete definition of the [incomplete beta function](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/02/02/) and the [regularized beta function](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/BetaRegularized/02/02/) given at the [functions.Wolfram.com](http://functions.wolfram.com) site. For certain special combinations of parameters, both the hypergeometric form, and the equivalent integral, need to be evaluated differently. Also, Matlab's `beta` function will produce errors in these situations as well, as it's based on `gammaln` under the hood in order to be numerically careful. The symbolic beta function can be used as a substitute: `double(beta(sym(a),sym(b)))` or `mfun('beta',a,b)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the equivalence with [Gauss' hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) to write, instead of `betainc(z,a,b)`,

```
z.^a/a.*hypergeom([a,1-b],a+1,z) / beta(a,b)
```

This requires scalar `a` and `b`, and is slower than `betainc` (for the values for which the latter is defined, that is).

Comment: `betainc` is a numeric function, which is probably why it only supports z on [0, 1]. See [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/480175/80812) for some possibilities on speeding up Matlab's `hypergeom`.