# Fast Matlab Code for hypergeometric function $_2F_1$

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, matlab, computational-mathematics

I am looking for a good numerical algorithm to evaluate the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ in Matlab ([`hypergeom`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hypergeom.html) in Matlab is very slow). I looked across the Internet, but did not find anything useful. Does anybody here have an idea where to find a fast algorithm to compute this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is Matlab source code for J. Pearson's master's thesis "Computation of Hypergeometric Functions". The thesis is a available as 
http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/porterm/research/pearson_final.pdf
and the Matlab code URL is http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/porterm/research/hypergeometricpackage.zip (I cannot judge the code because I am working with Pascal/Delphi).

Comment: I will have a look at it, thank you

Answer (score 8):

A while back I wrote some simple Matlab code to implement the [Gaussian Hypergeometric function](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/) $_2F_1$: [get it here](https://github.com/horchler/hypergeomq/blob/master/other/hypergeom2F1.m). The code is based on the function's [infinite sum representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/01/), which means that it’s only valid inside the complex unit circle, i.e., ${\mid}z{\mid} \lt 1$ (no analytic continuation is performed, but [these transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Transformation_formulas) might be useful if you need to do that). It’s much faster than Matlab’s [`hypergeom`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hypergeom.html) function (and permits you to specify a tolerance), but you should confirm that it gives satisfactory results (especially for ${\mid}z{\mid} \approx 1$ where you may need to adjust tolerances or increase the number of iterations) in the regime that you're interested in. The code from [J. Pearson](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/porterm/research/hypergeometricpackage.zip) mentioned in the other answer is nice for learning about various methods and may be useful in other parameter regimes, but it doesn't seem to written with performance in mind – though it may still be faster than full symbolic evaluation using `hypergeom`.

Another alternative is to more-efficiently evaluate Matlab’s symbolic `hypergeom` itself. You can [try my `hypergeomq` function](https://github.com/horchler/hypergeomq) (tested in R2016a and R2013b; may require modification to work in earlier versions). This function uses the same underlying compiled code, but performs some optimizations in the conversion from floating-point to symbolic math and back. The speedup for $_2F_1$ probably won't be very dramatic, but for other forms it can be significant (e.g., an order of magnitude speed up for $_2F_2$ in some cases).

Comment: thank you, i will give it try, although i probably can perform those results not before monday, but thanks in advance.