# Analytical solution to $\int \frac{x^k}{1-x}dx$?

Tags: integration

Is there any simple way to get this integral? I'm also using Wolfram Alpha, but I get the solution below. I need specific  answer not function that depends on a summation like a hypergeometric function.
$$
\int \frac{x^k}{1-x}dx = \frac{x^{k + 1}\sideset{_2}{_1}F(1, k + 1, k + 2, x)}{k + 1} + C
$$
The problem related to summation below:
$$
\begin{align}
S=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{k+n}\quad,k\in[0,2\pi]\\
S=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{k+n}\\
x^kS=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+n}}{k+n}\\
\frac{d}{dx} (x^kS)=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k+n)x^{k+n-1}}{k+n}\quad,\text{if $|x|\lt 1 $}\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{k+n-1}=\frac{x^k}{1-x}\\
\int\frac{d}{dx} (x^kS)dx=&\int\frac{x^k}{1-x}dx
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If $k$ is allowed to be any real, I wouldn't expect a nicer answer than that.

Comment: How about [these](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/26/01/02/0002/) [identities](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0025/) ?

Comment: Also, if `x` is in the unit circle as it seems, there are quite simple algorithms to numerically evaluate that Gaussian Hypergeometric function if that's what you're worried about. See my code linked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/480175/80812

Comment: Express the integral as a finite sum
$$\int \frac{x^k}{1-x}dx=-\ln |x-1|- \sum_{j=1}^k \binom kj \frac{(x-1)^j}j
$$

Comment: @Quanto: Except that it's indicated that $k \in [0,2\pi]$ in the question.

Comment: @horchler - you are right

Comment: @TymaGaidash Can you take $b=0$ there?

Comment: For $x \in \mathbb C$ such that $|x-1|<1$, @Quanto's answer becomes a convergent infinite series: $$\int \frac{x^k}{1-x}dx=-\ln (x-1)- \sum_{j=1}^\infty \binom kj \frac{(x-1)^j}j$$

Comment: @Gary Yes, you should see [these results](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.06515.pdf) for $b=0$ in the incomplete Beta function, but $b=0$ in the Lerch function link gives $0$ instead of $1$. Of course  [the $\lim\limits_{b\to0}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.01+Lerch%28z%2C1%2C0.01%29) works

Answer (score -4):

$$
\int {\frac{{x^k }}{{1 - x}}dx} 
$$
Let, $1-x = t$. Then, $-dx = dt$. On substituting this,
$$
\int\frac{(1-t)^k}{t}(-dt) = \int\frac{1}{t}\sum_{r}\binom{k}{r}(-t)^r(-dt)  = -\ln t + \sum_{r}\binom{k}{r}\frac{(-t)^r}{r} .
$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that in the question $k$ is tipically not a positive integer but a real number between $0$ and $2\pi$.